# socat as argument to ssh: "bash: socat: command not found"

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ssh, socat

If I ssh into an osx box from a linux box, issuing socat works fine. However, if I give the socat command as argument to ssh it fails. `socat` was installed in osx using `brew`. Any idea why this is happening?

```
This works:
  $ ssh daniel@remoteOSX
  $ socat -d -d SYSTEM:date -
  < date shows up here :) >

This fails:
  $ ssh daniel@remoteOSX 'socat -d -d SYSTEM:date -'
  Password:
  bash: socat: command not found                                <-- The ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, plain `ssh` does not use *your* PATH. Recreate your environment by spawning a login shell.

```
ssh daniel@remoteOSX 'bash -lc "socat -d -d SYSTEM:date -"'
```